# How to assert a JSON key but not care about values in Java?

Tags: json, spring-boot, junit, assert

I want to test that a certain key exists in the JSON at the root level.

```
 MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.token").exists())
                .andReturn();
```

I can do the test using jsonPath inside MockMVC class.

But if I already have a string of json, how do I assert it?

```
Assert(jsonString, hasKey??)
```

Comment: jsonPath() just delegates to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/JsonPathExpectationsHelper.html. You can create an instance by yourself and call its methods.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the path of the json like below

```
String tree =
        "{\n"
            + "  \"tes\": {\n"
            + "    \"test1\":\"test12111\"\n"
            + "  }\n"
            + "}";

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
  String value = jsonNode.path("tes").path("test1").textValue();
```

if value is null the path does not exists, if you get non null value then the path exists